# Delphi and PAServer

Tags: delphi, paserver

Is it possible to install two versions of Delphi's PAServer and PAServer Manager on a Mac?

For reasons I will not go into, I need to switch between using Delphi 11.2 and Delphi 11.3 to program for Apple devices. I am using a Mac Mini for this. Every time I switch between the two Delphi versions, I keep getting the error that the wrong PAServer is running on the Mac, and I need to reinstall the other version of PAServer to continue working. PAServer for 11.2 is verison 13.2.11.7. 11.3 is 13.3.12.6.

Note: I understand I can't run both versions of PAServer on the Mac at the same time, just need to be able to start one or the other depending on what version of Delphi I am using.

I also tried renaming the PAServer folder/app on the Mac before running the install for the other PAServer, but it appears the installed version simply gets overwritten by the new install. I don't use the Mac system for anything other than programming, so maybe I am doing something wrong when renaming the folder/app.

Update: Looks like I was looking at the wrong app. It appears it is the PAServerManager app that is misbehaving. When I double click the two PAServer.app icons, the terminal screens that appear do show the different versions numbers. However, when I double click either of the PAServerManager.app icons, add a server, then start said server, both PAServerManager apps start a terminal using the last PAServer.app program I installed. Also, if I rename both of the PAServer-22.0 apps, then the PAServerManager fails to start the server.

So I guess the question should be, how do I set up the PAServerManager.app to use the correct PAServer-22.0.app folder after I rename it? Either that or how to I create and start a server using only the PAServer_22.0 app?

Comment: When I rename the PAServer folder, (eg. rename PAServer 22.0 to PAServer 22.2, for Delphi 11.2), then install PAServer for Delphi 11.3, it does not overwrite the first install. No idea why yours would.

Answer (score 1):

You can install differents versions of PAServer on a MAC changing default port.
[See the documentation for change the port](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Running_the_Platform_Assistant_on_a_Mac#Example:_Setting_the_Port_Number_When_You_Start_PAServer_from_the_Command_Line) (if it's in use or you would change it).

After, in you different versions of Delphi, configure the connection to the appropiate port (PAServer verison).

Comment: This is useful info, but does not seem to answer the current question, which is not about running two PAServers at the same time, but about managing to get two versions of PAServer installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem: 2 different Delphi versions with 2 different PAServer versions. I've done the following, I renamed the PAServer installer to the corresponding Delphi version so I could intall both versions. I haven't installed in different ports to try to connect both PAServers at the same time, though...